# How to install PHPWord library using composer

Tags: php

I am trying to install PHPWord library of PHP using composer but i cant install.

I have tried to follow https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord.

Comment: What problem are you experiencing? Have you used Composer before? Does it fail to install on your system? The instructions [are fairly clear](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord#installation), even linking to the official Composer documentation on dependencies.

Answer (score 8):

Run this command in the root of your project to add the dependency to composer.json and install the librarie:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpword
```

Comment: and where are the actual files located?

Answer (score 4):

Run this command in the root of your project
**$ composer require phpoffice/phpword**

You will find vendor folder and 2 files composer.json and composer.lock in the root folder of your project.

Create a new file, index.php, in the root folder of the project(or some other filename). Copy paste the basic usage sample code provided in https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Change the line
**require_once 'bootstrap.php';**
to
**require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';**

Run the new file created and then you can see the docx file created in the root folder of your project.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add dependency on PHPWord into your package. just below code in your composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
       "phpoffice/phpword": "v0.13.*"
    }
}
```

and then execute the below code from console

```
$ composer.phar install
```

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest version from https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/releases

You first need to add the installed version to the composer.json file :

```
"version": "0.13.0"
```

And run the below command in cmd

```
$ composer require phpoffice/phpword
```

**Make sure you have installed composer in your system**